# images2gif Throws "Cannot get palette" Error

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a simple script to download a series of radar images, add overlays to them, then turn them into an animated gif.
I'm using Pillow and images2gif from the visvis package.
I asked a question earlier about stacking the transparent gif files. 
I managed to get this working, but images2gif is throwing an error.
Here is the relevant code from my project:

```
from PIL import Image
from visvis.vvmovie.images2gif import writeGif as gif

background = Image.open("%IMAGEDIR%\Background.png")
overlay = Image.open("%IMAGEDIR%\Overlay.png")
frames = []
for i in range (10, 0, -1):
    imagenum = ("%02d" % i)
    radar = Image.open("%IMAGEDIR%\" + imagenum + ".gif")
    radar = radar.convert("RGBA")
    background.paste(radar, (0,0), radar)
    background.paste(overlay, (0,0), overlay)
    background.convert("RGB").convert("P", palette = Image.ADAPTIVE)
    frames.append(background)
print ("Writing image!")
gif("%IMAGEDIR%\animation.gif", frames)
print ("Done!")
```

However, this throws an error from images2gif:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "%IMAGEDIR%\images.py", line 62, in <module>
    gif("%IMAGEDIR%\animation.gif", frames)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\visvis\vvmovie\images2gif.py", line 578, in writeGif
gifWriter.writeGifToFile(fp, images, duration, loops, xy, dispose)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\visvis\vvmovie\images2gif.py", line 418, in writeGifToFile
   raise RuntimeError('Cannot get palette. '
RuntimeError: Cannot get palette. Maybe you should try imageio instead.
```

Going to the relevant lines in images2gif, I find this:

```
# Obtain palette for all images and count each occurance
palettes, occur = [], []
for im in images:
    palette = getheader(im)[1]
    if not palette:
        palette = PIL.ImagePalette.ImageColor
        if isinstance(palette, type(os)):
            # Older or newer? version of Pil(low)
            data = PIL.ImagePalette.ImagePalette().getdata()
            palette = data[0].encode('utf-8') + data[1]
            # Arg this does not work. Go use imageio
            raise RuntimeError('Cannot get palette. '
                               'Maybe you should try imageio instead.')
    palettes.append(palette)
for palette in palettes:
    occur.append(palettes.count(palette))
```

I've never used imageio, and I'm already using PIL which is supposed to work with images2gif. Ideally, I don't want to have to save the images to the disk -- they are small files, but I'd like to get this working however I can.

Thanks a lot for any help!

NOTE: I'm using Python 3.4 on Windows 10 with numpy 1.9.2 and visvis 1.9.2 to test it, but this script is going to be used on PythonAnywere.

Answer (score 4):

Try this version, works with me (with pillow 2.9): https://github.com/rec/echomesh/blob/master/code/python/external/images2gif.py

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion. At least now it looks like the only place this messes up is on saving the gif which is a HUGE improvement. It is throwing the following error when it tries to save though: `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface` It is throwing this error on line 445 of images2gif.py which is `fp.write(encoded(header))`

Comment: Well, I changed the `fp.write(encode(SOMETHING))` lines in the saving routine to `fp.write(SOMETHING.encode())` which eliminated the above error. The program now runs, but when I try to open the gif in GIMP, I get a `Value out of range for code size` error. So, it seems like it IS saving something, but not a valid gif. Now I'm just really confused as to how to fix it.